# "Wireless disabled by hardware switch" after suspend and other hardware buttons ineffective - how can I solve this?

Tags: wireless, shortcut-keys, keyboard

I have recently purchased a Novatech nFinity N1410 laptop and am having problems with the wireless, which

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

tells me is Centrino Wireless-N 2230 and using the iwlwifi driver.

The problem is that after the device has been suspended, I am not able to get the wireless working again without a restart. The network indicator states that the wireless disabled by hardware switch.

Though <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is meant to be the wireless switch,

```
xev
```

tells me that the system doesn't see it as anything at all when I press this hardware combination. Also, though the brightness up/down buttons work fine, the volume up/down buttons do not work either.

What can I do to fix this? I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with all available updates installed.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't bumped a switch anywhere on the outside of your laptop? I've done that on more than one occasion.

Comment: @DaimyoKirby The hardware Fn button is Fn + F2, however this does not do anything at all. Also, after a restart, the wireless starts working again.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into buying one of these and have been looking for potential problems, looks like your solution can be found in the novatech forums:

1. Simply created a new file called `brcm.sh`
2. Inserted the below code and save:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Simple bash script to fix resume from suspend issues...
   # Place this script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/
   # then chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/brcm.sh

   case $1 in
     hibernate)
       /sbin/modprobe -r brcm80211
     ;;
     suspend)
       /sbin/modprobe -r brcm80211
     ;;
     resume)
       /sbin/modprobe brcm80211
     ;;
     thaw)
       /sbin/modprobe brcm80211
     ;;
   esac
   ```
3. Placed it in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`
4. Made it executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/brcm.sh
   ```

Source: http://forum.novatech.co.uk/showthread.php?25709-nFinity-N1411-solved-Ubuntu-12-10-install-and-wifi-wake-from-suspend&p=331411

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i have no hardware switch just F2 for disabling and enabling wifi
instead of using unblock wifi
try blocking it 
using

```
$ sudo rfkill block wifi
```

i know it sounds crazy but it worked for me and i'm using a dell laptop
and we have the same wifi driver
after using unblock

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

after using block

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

and to remove the soft block just click on the wifi button on the top right corner of your unity desktop and select Enable Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

You can use this command to unblock all wireless devices: From the terminal,

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

You can also run

```
rfkill list all
```

to find out whether it is a software block or rather a hardware block

You may have to reinstall the driver

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If wireless begins working again, you can create scripts in /etc/pm to do this each time you suspend and resume.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/modules
```

...and added the line...

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. rfkill says that my wireless is hard blocked. However, my hardware switch, Fn + F2 doesn't register as doing anything at all. The wireless is fixed after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

For my dell D630 notebook, the following has worked, to solve the `"Soft blocked: yes"` wifi after a suspend:

```
sudo rmmod wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

After typing this the wifi has returned. No reboot required anymore, a success!

Seems re-initializing the kernel module solves the problem.

(wl, the wireless kernel module, I have a broadcom wifi, the kernel module name might differ)

You might try this at `/etc/pm/sleep.d/brcm.sh` when the system is returning from a suspend as noted by John White.

I have an ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing wicd `sudo apt-get install wicd` and completely remove network-manager `sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager` it fixed all Wi-fi problems on my Acer C720 including yours.